# Showing that the operator norm is equal to the q-norm.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in L^q([0,1])$ and let $F:L^p([0,1])\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$Fg=\int^1_0f(x)g(x)dx.$$
Show that $\|F\|=\|f\|_q$. Here $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm defined to be $$\|F\|=\sup\left\{\frac{\|F_g\|}{\|g\|}:g\in L^p([0,1])\text{ and }g\neq0\right\},$$ $\|\cdot\|_q$ is the norm on $L^q$ and $p,q\in(1,\infty)$ are conjugate exponents.

I have established the $(\leq)$ part by applying the Holder's Inequality on $|F_g|$. However, I have no bearing as to what to do on the $(\geq)$ part. Can somebody provide some hints on how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is that we want to choose $g$ in such a way that $fg \ge 0$ and $\int_0^1 f(x)g(x) \, dx = \|f\|^q_q$. Therefore let 
$$ g(x) := \def\s{\operatorname{sgn}}\s f(x) \cdot \left|f(x)\right|^{q-1} $$
Then, as $p = \frac{q}{q-1}$, we have
$$ \def\a#1{\left|#1\right|}\a{g(x)}^p = \a{f(x)}^q $$
that is $g \in L^p$ and 
$$ \def\n#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\n{g}^p_p = \n f_q^q \iff \n g_p = \n f_q^{q/p} = \n f_q^{q-1}$$
Therefore, as $Fg = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x) \,dx = \int_0^1 \a{f(x)}^q\, dx = \n f_q^q$, we have
$$ \n F \ge \frac{\a{Fg}}{\n g_p} = \frac{\n f_q^q}{\n f_q^{q-1}} = \n f_q $$
This proves the missing inequality.